# Flurry authorization key

Tags: flurry

I can't find my Flurry authorization key for push credentials. How can I obtain a new one?

I see that this is not something available from the interface: "Receive the token code to access the API. Save the token, there is no interface available to recall the token. (Keep this token secure. This token cannot be retrieved from Flurry systems.)"

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a new programmatic user, which will then generate a new token for you to use with the API.

Log into y.flurry.com
Select the Admin icon from the left navigation bar
Select Users
Click on +Programmatic User